# Migrating attribute scope from antlr3 to antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3

It was [possible](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Using+both+global+and+local+%28rule%29+attribute+scopes) to use rule `scope` blocks in ANTLR3:

```
formUsage
scope {
    Form form;
}
:   formUsage1
|   formUsage2
|   formUsage3
;

formUsage1
:   someUsage { $formUsage::form = ... ; }   
...
```

We have some large parts of our grammar that operate on one specific object. `scope` block was a nice feature for implementing some common state inside a specific rule and all subrules. Alternatively we could pass this common state as a parameter to all subrules or put it to global `@parser::members`. But `scope` block was exactly what we need.

What is the better way to migrate this blocks to ANTLR4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want now are locals, which are part of [Rule Attribute Definitions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#rule-attribute-definitions). The syntax for a parser rule in ANTLR4 is:

```
rulename[args] returns [retvals] locals [localvars] : ... ;
```

The `locals` section is kept as given and not parsed by ANTLR4. This allows for any target specific code there.